# Bootstrap 5 Text can't be centered

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have to make a website for school, but for some reason I can't center Text.
I want the Text to be in the middle of the Background picture. I tried everything but can't get it to work.
Heres My HTML: `pastebin.com/0tTLKH5u`
And here my CSS: `pastebin.com/Nzy33fWe`

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make the whole body a `flex` and then adjust everything. That is a better solution, but would need a fairly large rewrite of the CSS. Quick solution is to make the text an `absolutely positioned` and center it.
Adding the following CSS to the texts' class, should do the trick:

```
.display-1 {
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  letter-spacing: 40px;
  transition: ease-in 1s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

The body is the relative element here, and your element is then moved to start at 50% `top` & `left` of the `body`, then positioned centered using `translate` by moving it -50% in both the axes.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you want?

```css
div {
  width:300px; 
  height:300px; 
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/300/300"); 
  color:#000; 
  text-shadow:2px 2px #fff;
  display:flex;   
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size:30px;
 }
```

```html
<div>Welcome</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attached an example where text is centered over the background image. I had used `padding` to align the text at the center from both horizontal and vertical fronts.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: url("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/nebula_blue.s2014.png");
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 52px;
  color: white;
  padding:20% 20%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello PalowPower !</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```